# Wildcard over ssh not working

Tags: linux, ssh, wildcard

I'm having trouble using a wildcard via ssh. The command I'm trying to run is `ssh -t host "sudo ls -l /root/.ssh/id_rsa*`.

I've tried to use single quotes, and also use `sudo -s`. I've also tried quoting the wildcard itself, but nothing seems to work. Other people have seemed to use some combination of these solutions, but it hasn't worked for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I've tried, you will have to spawn a new shell to prevent the wildcard from being expanded before authenticating as root:

```
ssh -t host "sudo -s bash -c \"ls -l /root/.ssh/id_rsa*\""
```

Comment: You can also do `echo "ls -l /root/.ssh/id_rsa*" | ssh host sudo bash`